# file parameter in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am developing declarative pipeline and want to use file parameter to read its content, but its not working as expected

```
parameters{
        file(fileLocation:'list.txt', description:'contains list of projects to be build')
   }
```

I am getting following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 12: Invalid parameter "fileLocation", did you mean "description"? @ line 12, column 14.
           file(fileLocation:'release-list.txt', description:'contains list of projects to be build')
```

Following is another option mentioned for basic step plugin

```
readFile: Read file from workspace
Reads a file from a relative path (with root in current directory, usually workspace) and returns its content as a plain string.
file
Relative ( /-separated) path to file within a workspace to read.
Type: String
encoding (optional)
Type: String
```

its working in script step like

```
def myfile = readFile('list.txt')
echo "${myfile}"
```

But how to use it directly in declarative script as we used other basic steps like dir??

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the plug-in https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/.

This plug-in adds support for file parameters in your Jenkinsfile: https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/#plugin-content-usage-in-declarative-pipeline

```
parameters {
  base64File 'small'
  stashedFile 'large'
}
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/file-parameters-plugin

Answer (score 1):

The correct arguments for the file parameter are `name` and `description`. So it should be:

```
file(name:'list.txt', description:'contains list of projects to be build')
```

However there's an open jenkins issue dating back from 2015 about the file parameter not working for pipelines, so I don't think even this will solve your issue. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax is working

```
parameters{
        file name:'list.txt', description:'contains list of projects to be build'
   }
```

But fileLocation parameter is not acceptable still.

Below syntax is available in Jenkins2 Up & Running book but its not working

```
parameters{
        file(fileLocation:'list.txt', description:'contains list of projects to be build')
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Till outstanding issues gets fixed, I believe we may have to stick to freestyle mode & handle things either in downstream pipeline job or within same job leveraging needy plugin feature.

Here is my attempt which looks to work file irrespective (yes supports Binaries as well) types : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7mQ.png

`${list.txt}` will point to right file in your case..