# trying to attach a file as a parameter in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins

here is my code:

I am building a jenkins pipleine but dont know how to attach a file as a parameter step

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'abc' } }

    stages {
        stage('Running for : MQ Injection') {
            steps {
                echo 'Injectiong Messages in dev'
                build job: 'MQTask_Publisher', parameters: [string(name: 'mq.host', value: mqhost), string(name: 'mq.port', value: mqport), string(name: 'mq.manager', value: mqmanager), string(name: 'mq.channel', value: mqchannel),string(name: 'mq.queue', value: mqqueue),string(name: 'mq.wait.seconds', value: mqwaitseconds),string(name: 'fileType', value: fileType)]
                
            }
        } 
  
    
     stage('Running for : MQ Message validation') {
            steps {
                echo 'Validating messages created from MQ'
                build job: 'MQInjection_Validation', parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: env), string(name: 'TRN', value: trn), string(name: 'Min Date', value: minDate), string(name: 'Max Date', value: maxDate), string(name: 'Creation time', value: time)]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you end up getting this to work I highly suggest you dont do this.  The Jenkins file upload is notoriously limited.  When we want to share across different jobs we upload to s3 then pass the bucket/key as a param into another job

Comment: As Chris suggests, you should probably look at uploading the file somewhere that's outside Jenkins, then have Jenkins download it. If that's not possible, then does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480440/file-parameter-in-declarative-pipeline